# Getting multiple checkbox values in loop

Tags: php, jquery

Below is my code

```
if (!empty($_POST['ok'])) {
    $errorMessage = array();


    $loopcount = 0;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['theDate'] AS $i => $theDate) {
        if ($_POST['EW'][$i] == 'EW') {
            $ew = "yes";
        } else {
            $ew = "no";
        }
        $i = $i + 1;

        echo $ew;
    }
}
```

its pulls the checkbox value of below and assigns it yes or now if value == ew

```
E/W<input name="EW[]" ID="EW[]" value="EW" type="checkbox" />
```

the issue is if  check these

```
row  checked
1      no
2      yes
3      no
3      yes
```

the out result when submitted is

```
row  checked
1      yes
2      yes
3      no
4      no
```

It seems to stick anything checked as ew to the top and I don't get why here is a live working example that when submit is clicked echos with output.... all fields need to be filled but is u just add a number i will work

http://runningprofiles.com/tests/addbet.php

Comment: add '{' to your foreach

Comment: Sorry that was a copy and paste mistake on my behalf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox is not submitted, if it does not have a value, thus, the 'yes' are the only ones in the loop. the index numbers for that field only from the submitted ones.

edit - clearification: if not checked - it its value does not get submitted.

Comment: so how do i fix it? as i really want it so its in order so i know which ones where ticked and which where not when storing into my database

Comment: you could add a on submit javascript to set the values to x and check the unchecked ones - or generate id=EW[] as EW[n] -- that allows you to add a `<hidden id="EW[1]" value="default" /> <input type="checkbox" id="EW[1]" value="overwrites if checked" />` ... while generating the rows, just increase a count and use it as n for all fields in that row. removing a row does not matter in case of the count, since you loop with `foreach` over the available fields.

Comment: perfect thanks used the following code to do the needful: <hidden id="EW[1]" value="default" /> <input type="checkbox" id="EW[1]" value="overwrites if checked" />

Answer (score 0):

> foreach ($_POST['theDate'] AS $i => $theDate)

You missing the { at the end

like this

> foreach ($_POST['theDate'] AS $i => $theDate){

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my bahalf when copying the code over here